# not updating value in each loop of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loopin all the anchor tags for tracing the ul of that anchor tag.

My aim is to cahnge the class name of that ul tag if matches.

Unfortunately inside each loop, every time it is going into if condition even though I changed the value of n inside if condition.

```
var fileName = location.pathname.split("/").slice(-1)
    //var url = window.location.href;
    var n = -1;
    alert(fileName);
    $("[id$=sample] a").each(function () {
        n = this.href.indexOf(fileName);
        if (n != -1)
        {
            alert(this.href);
            alert(n); alert(fileName);
            n = -1;
        }           
        console.log(this.href);
    });
```

Comment: What is the value of `fileName` and what are the `href` values? Please post the HTML containing the `href` values and also the value of `fileName`.

Comment: Filename value will be as our url page name like HomePage.aspx or LoginPage.aspx those will come dynamically.

Comment: Setting the value of `n` manually doesn't do anything because it's set to a new value again at the start of the next loop. The question is somewhat unclear, but if you want to stop the loop after the first match you have to `return false`.

Comment: @SriaknthReddy So the filename is `HomePage.aspx` or `LoginPage.aspx` and what are your anchor tags? `n = this.href.indexOf(fileName);` is most likely always returning a value higher than `-1` and as `JJJ` said, you have not given any specific indication if you want to loop through all or break out after the match. Though `My aim is to cahnge the class name of that ul tag if matches.` looks like you only want a single match and then leave the loop.

Comment: @fran anchor tag can contain any url. It comes dynamically from back end.

Comment: @jjj Thanks for your answer. It worked for my requirement.

Comment: @SriaknthReddy I know that all values are dynamic but if you are being cryptic to the exact values its hard to tell if the issue is logical or based on a value you are processing at time of failure. Luckily a few guesses were enough to help.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and comparing `pathname` of the `<a>` to `location.pathname` directly

```
$("[id$=sample] a").filter(function () {
   return this.pathname === location.pathname;       
}).addClass('current-page-class');
```

Comment: I needs to add class to the ul of that anchor tag.

Comment: Show sample html structure. Can change to `.closest('ul').addClass('current-page-class');` but if you have nested ul need to see html and associated classes and expected results